# Using JQuery Validate remote method with array

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, validation, jquery-validate

I need to register more users in the same screen, so I use a form like this:

```
Username*<input name="username[]" />
Password*<input name="password[]" />

Username*<input name="username[]" />
Password*<input name="password[]" />
```

...

and using jquery.validate to control if the user is still in use:

```
rules : {
'username[]' : {
    required : true,
    remote: {
            url: "control_user.php"

          }
},
```

BUT I don't know what to do in control_user.php to return the right 'true' or 'false' for every 'username' in the array.

Any Help??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are some really useful demos in the validation project files - you can download them as a zip [here](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/archive/master.zip)

you can just return the strings 'true' or 'false' from your php script.  I think your 'control_user.php' will look a lot like this example taken from the 'marketo' demo

```
<?php
$request = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['email']));
$emails = array('glen@marketo.com', 'george@bush.gov', 'me@god.com');
$valid = 'true';
foreach($emails as $email) {
    if( strtolower($email) == $request )
        $valid = 'false';
}
echo $valid;
?>
```